# Deploy app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using docker-compose

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a multi-container app to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using docker-compose. My folder structure is as follows:

```
AppDirectory/
  app/
  proxy/
  scripts/
  static/
  docker-compose.yml
  Dockerfile
  requirements.txt
```

I've got the images built and pushed into Docker Hub. Also, the environment is working as expected when running `docker-compose up` in development. Using AWS Elastic Beanstalk dashboard, I create an application and then I proceed to create an environment, using Docker as platform. I have a `.zip` folder with the structure mentioned before.

When creating the environment, there's first a console log telling me that `Configuration files cannot be extracted from the application version appname-source. Check that the application version is a valid zip or war file.`
Not sure what it means here, as I'm uploading a `.zip` file and inside there are Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.

After it says the app deployed successfully, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error from nginx and then I have the environment with severe health and updating for hours without changes. I've been following the documentation regarding this and I believe it is possible to deploy it with docker-compose.yml, however I'm wondering if my configuration is enough? I linked the Docker Hub images also inside my docker-compose. I'm not able to request logs neither as the state must be 'ready', and it is constantly 'updating'.

Anyone with any experience with such deployment that wants to share any tips or configuration settings? Thank you.